# How can 2 jar libraries use log4j independently?

Tags: java, logging, hadoop, jar, log4j

I did an application that makes use of log4j. Everything works fine, however, when I make a jar of that application and attach it to another application the logging stops working (no log file is created). I think the problem is that this last application also includes another jar (besides mine) that already use log4j. By the way, this other jar is hadoop, and I think it is taking the log context. My log4j properties file is in classpath, as well as in the root of the jar:

> log4j.logger.a.b.c=DEBUG, A1
>
> log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>   log4j.appender.A1.File=my-log.log
>   log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p
>   %c{2}: %m%n

What can I do to sort this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the same log file for both applications (my-log.log)?

Comment: The properties file I posted is in the classpath and the only one outside a jar. I just want to log my application, so I didn't add anything about the other jars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, what I can think of is that may be HBase's or Hadoop's log4j.properties is shadowing your *log4j.properties* file that's in your resources directory as, HBase is using it's own *log4j.properties* file first already in the classpath.

In the *log4j.properties* used by HBase or Hadoop, you probably don't have your '*A1*' appender set which can actually log to '*my-log.log*'

Secondly, If you are not configuring log4j using `PropertyConfigurator.configure(path to your customLog4j.properties);` at the beginning of your application, then it's more likely that log4j.properties of the HBase or Hadoop is being picked up.

Finally, what I can suggest to experiment, if you already have not tried with `PropertyConfigurator.configure()`, is to rename your application specific log4j.properties file to something else say *mylog4j.properties* and try using that in PropertyConfigurator as `PropertyConfigurator.configure(mylog4j.properties);`

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using Hadoop. Are you running this on an HDFS? If so Hadoop is configured to use the log4j properties file located on HDFS. So you would need to update that log file.

In general, log4j.properties contained within jar files are ignored. This is because it is the driving application that should have control of what logging it wants done regardless of what logging the libraries that it uses want. If I am creating an app I don't have a log file created for every library I use. I use a single log4j config file and from there can control the logging of all libraries.

Comment: If @user252816 is not getting any actual runtime errors, the problem is almost certainly that the configuration in use is just not set to log his stuff; putting a `log4j.properties` in a jar is fine (as a fallback and an example), but it's usually shadowed.

Comment: I'm not running this over HDFS. This is just an HBase client application that requires the hadoop jar.

I tried to create that single log4j config for the application I'm using, thereby creating a folder named resources with the properties file within and putting it in the classpath. The config I used is the same that is in my question post. However, it was not effective, since only hadoop/hbase logging was performed (and not the logging of my jar library).

Answer (score 0):

as you said the application which you are creating has log4j, that doesnt matter when you are making it into jar, because jar wont have your log4j while devloping , once you convert it to jar. all you need to know aware is , that you need use logger same as the application which your jar will be added as dependency.

let us if it war and your jar will be part of it, then you jar will use the log4j property which war uses. so you need to check whether you use same log4j which your target application uses, and also check the log property file and it logger file, you may get your jar logs there may be, i mean the different log file location than what you have configure in you jar log4j file property

Answer (score 0):

Using `PropertyConfigurator.configure();` should solve your problem. Make sure that you use it while the application is loading the configuration.